# Binding Part of 'TextBlock' in UWP

Tags: text, binding, win-universal-app, partial, textblock

Any idea on how to only bind part of 'TextBlock.Text' string.

For example:

I want to add the "Your name is {Binding Path=Name}" and have 'OneWay Binding' without having to use another 'TextBlock' control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the text in your Bindings into Runs:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run>Your name is</Run>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

It's possible that you run into issues with the whitespaces between the Runs in such a case. You can use the attribute xml:space="preserve" on TextBlock in this case.